# How do I need to start a background thread using MouseListener?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, mouselistener

The idea of my code is that the moment my mouse enters a specific jscrollpane it starts to print out the rgb-values under it. 
And I want it to stop printing out these rgb-values the moment my mouse exits the jscrollpane.

```
try{
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Bernard\\Documents\\viking\\map\\provinces.bmp";
    Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    lblMap = new JLabel(icon);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.add(lblMap);
    provincesPanel.add(jScrollPane1);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jp);
    jScrollPane1.setAlignmentX(JFrame.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    jScrollPane1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        mapMuis =true;
        SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker<Color, Color>() {

                @Override
                protected Color doInBackground() {
                    while (mapMuis==true){
                    pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                    point = pointer.getLocation();
                    color = robot.getPixelColor((int) point.getX(), (int) point.getY());
                    System.out.println("Color at: " + point.getX() + "," + point.getY() + " is: " + color);
                    return color;
                    }
                    return color;
                }
            };
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
        mapMuis=false;
    }
});
```

I am however getting no output at all when my mouse enters the jscrollpane.

Thank you for your time.

Solution:
I chukked out the MouseListener and implemented the MouseMotion:

```
            jScrollPane1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                    pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                    point = pointer.getLocation();
                    color = robot.getPixelColor((int) point.getX(), (int) point.getY());
                    System.out.println("Color at: " + point.getX() + "," + point.getY() + " is: " + color); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });
```

Comment: So, why do you need a thread, why not use a combination of MouseListener and MouseMotionListener, so you can track the enter and exit events and update the RGB value on the mouseMoved event?

Comment: As a general debugging tip, try adding printlns all along the chain of events that's not working like you'd expect. That is, you have one in the `doInBackground` method, but why not one in `mouseEntered` so you know that part of the plumbing works?

Comment: Calling return will exit your method, meaning that you'll only get one loop out of your doInBackground method. Instead, you should be using the publish and process methods

Comment: General noobishness and confusion with my thread about the checkbox. I threw out the checkbox but I kept thinking I would need Multithreading...

Comment: What does the JScrollPane hold? An image? If so, I wouldn't use a Robot for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a `MouseMotionListener` and the `mouseMoved` event to achieve the same result without the need for any `Thread`s

Take a look at [How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: 1+.  Would you be more likely to add the MouseListener/MouseMotionListener to the viewport's view?